# Can't let my script produce a specific url using params

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script using python to fetch only the content showing how many data are there from a webpage. When I try the link used within my script I see the result something like `Showing 1-30 of 18893` (which is not what I want) but I get `Showing 1-30 of 196` (expected output) when I try the link below. The bottom line is> I get success using the direct link but get something else when the script use the url which has been produced by params.

[url of that site](https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&l=p%3ANY%3ANew_York%3AManhattan%3AAlphabet_City)

I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.yelp.com/search?"

params = {
    'find_desc': 'Restaurants',
    'find_loc': 'New York, NY',
    'l: p':'NY:New_York:Manhattan:Alphabet_City'
}

resp = requests.get(link,params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
total = soup.select_one("p:contains(Showing)").text
print(total)
```

Getting:

```
Showing 1-30 of 18894
```

Expected output:

```
Showing 1-30 of 196
```

Moreover, the link I get using `resp.url`:

```
https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&l%3A+p=NY%3ANew_York%3AManhattan%3AAlphabet_City
```

But the link I expect is:

```
https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&l=p%3ANY%3ANew_York%3AManhattan%3AAlphabet_City
```

***How can I make the script populate right url to the content?***

Comment: What's the difference between two `resp.url`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `'l: p':'NY:New_York:Manhattan:Alphabet_City'` parameter.

It's a good idea to use `urllib.parse.parse_qs` and then copy the parameters, rather than trying to decode it yourself.

Here's the fixed version:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.yelp.com/search"

params = {
    'find_desc': 'Restaurants',
    'find_loc': 'New York, NY',
    'l': 'p:NY:New_York:Manhattan:Alphabet_City'
}

res = requests.get(link,params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(res.url)
total = soup.select_one("p:contains(Showing)").text
print(total)
```

output:

```
https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&l=p%3ANY%3ANew_York%3AManhattan%3AAlphabet_City
Showing 1-30 of 196
```